# React-Native, render function to return a navigator.push

Tags: react-native

I need to move to the next screen using the navigator. My first code file has the navigator calling other screens (js files) in its render. In one of those, i want the render to goto next screen based on an if-else. I'm currently doing it like in the code.

```
render() { if (!this.state.loaded) return this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,}); }
```

but this doesnt work because "render requires to return a component". But Navigator is a component right? What am i doing wrong? How do i do this?

Comment: You might want to do it inside method shouldComponentUpdate instead of render. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: But that asks for a bool return. I just need to Skip to the next screen altogether.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to render one screen or another based on a state value. This decision should be handled by the parent component, not in the component it self.